# Removing an array and resorting the contents

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, methods

I'm writing a method in order to let the user be able to remove an element in the array. After it is removed, I would like to resort the array such that it does not have any empty gaps in between.

Here is my code:

```
public void remove(int position)
{
    if (position > currentCartSize)
    {
        System.out.println("Error! Nothing to remove.");
    }
    else if (isEmpty())
    {
        System.out.println("Error! Cart is empty.");
    }
    else
    {
        cart[position - 1] = null;
        currentCartSize--;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < currentCartSize; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 1; j < i; j++)
        {
            cart[j] = cart[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Why are you using an array in the first place instead of a `List`?

Comment: I'm not quite familiar with the List, never used it before.

Comment: Why are you assigning every cart[j] to the same cart[i]?

Comment: You would have to allocate a whole new array with the question you are asking and copy over all non-null elements. This requires more effort than just using a List like we've all said

Comment: You can use arrays... But then you have to implement what ArrayList is already providing: creating a smaller array and copying of the remaining elements. Sure that can be done ; but unless this is a learning exercise... You would be wasting your time reinventing a perfectly working wheel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try instead, implementing an ArrayList object, where you can use the array.remove(int position) method directly.

"The java.util.ArrayList.remove(int index) method removes the element at the specified position in this list. Shifts any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one from their indices)".
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't suggest removing values from a plain ol' array. I suggest using an ArrayList, you can remove elements seamlessly without there being gaps and they are just easier to work with than arrays. Best of luck :)

Comment: I've never actually used the ArrayList and it's the first time I hear about it.

Comment: using an array list is quite simple: All you would need to do to remove it is use the remove method so for example you declare an arraylist like this: ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>(); then you add values like this: a.add(1);a.add(2) etc etc. Then you would remove a certain value like this: a.remove(1) and it would remove the value 1 from the arraylist and all that would be left is 2

Comment: @Jake0991 then it's time to learn about it. You should use the best tool for each job, and an array is definitely the wrong solution here.

Comment: @Aaron So the arraylist length is defined by <Integer>? and when I add values, I'm assuming that the number entered is for the index position? If I decide the remove a content of the array, say position, it will automatically sort the array content?

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Of course. I'd like to know anything that makes the task at hand easier :)